# different sum() result from same column in python

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, nan, col

summary of process i had on a dataframe.

1. i got sum of the column 'damageDealt' which was 581294667.8516002

---

```
train.damageDealt.sum()
# 581294667.8516002
```

---

```
train.damageDealt.shape
# (4446966,)
```

2. i found there was one NaN value in a single column 'winPlacePerc'

---

```
train.isnull().sum()
        Id                 0
    groupId            0
    matchId            0
    assists            0
    boosts             0
    damageDealt        0
    DBNOs              0
    headshotKills      0
    heals              0
    killPlace          0
    killPoints         0
    kills              0
    killStreaks        0
    longestKill        0
    matchDuration      0
    matchType          0
    maxPlace           0
    numGroups          0
    rankPoints         0
    revives            0
    rideDistance       0
    roadKills          0
    swimDistance       0
    teamKills          0
    vehicleDestroys    0
    walkDistance       0
    weaponsAcquired    0
    winPoints          0
    winPlacePerc       1
    dtype: int64
```

---

3. value of column 'damageDealth' in the row which had NaN is 0.0

---

```
train[train.winPlacePerc.isnull() == True].damageDealt
#        2744604    0.0
#    Name: damageDealt, dtype: float64
```

---

4. i deleted that tuple by `dropna()`

---

```
train2 = train.copy()
train2.dropna(inplace=True)
train2[train2.winPlacePerc.isnull() == True]
# Series([], Name: damageDealt, dtype: float64)
```

---

5. sum of the column changed to 581294667.8516004 ...! even raised...!

---

```
train2.damageDealt.sum()
# 581294667.8516004
```

so i have no idea how this result came when only 0.0 tuple of damageDealt column deleted.
it would be helpful if anyone can explain this.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Seems like an issue with floating point arithmetic to me : https://www.floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: thanks for your help! but i still don't get it  about higher sum result when deleted value was 0.0. that means  actual values used for sum() are same ... am i right...?